# Services are not activating in ASUS_Z010D

Tags: android, android-service

I had started the service from the APPLICATION level by adding the following line of code.

```
    startService(new Intent(this, **********.class));
```

Then now the problem is if i restarted the device the services were automatically starting in all the devices but in ASUS_Z010D these services were not starting automatically, It was starting only when the app is opened.

Is there any way to solve this please let me know..... Thanks in Advance

Comment: might be worth checking if ASUS_Z010D needs some more permission to detect boot event from the receiver. I recall HTC, for example, used some special permissions in such cases

Comment: Thank u can u give me an example please....